# securing an application's http interface

Tags: c#, https

I have an .NET application that has a HTTP SOAP API, the interface is hosted by the application itself and not IIS. I don't have access to the source code. What are my  options on securing the communications with https?

I could write a wrapper and host that on IIS with a SSL cert, however that would be a lot of work if I want to expose all the APIs, unless there is an automated way?

Comment: You could use a [Reverse Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). Like [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use IIS and setup a new site. I then added a rewrite rule to this site which is a reverse proxy rule to the SOAP webservice. The new site was setup with SSL certificates. IIS handles converting HTTPS to HTTP.